# Best High Availability Solution for SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014, azure-sql-database, windows-server

Please we are about to implement High availability for for SQL server 2014 on our new infrastructure but i need to know which is best between SQL Failover Clustering and Always On High Availability Group. We needed to consider below as part of our requirement ;
1. Automatic Failover
2. Ensure that if storage hosting SQL database fails or get corrupted all data are moved to another Storage and still work perfectly with Automatic Failover
3. Needs to ensure that secondary(passive) node can used for reporting

I will be very happy if i can get assisted with above queries as well as advantages/Disadvantages of both Always on High availability and SQL Failover Clustering

Answer (score 0):

Always On Availability group will server your purpose for which you will need Enterprise Edition of SQL Server license. It will provide :

1. Automatic failover is available when the AG is configured with Synchronous-commit mode with automatic-failover.[Failover Modes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/failover-and-failover-modes-always-on-availability-groups?view=sql-server-2017)
2. Since AlwaysON has data separated for each instance that is part of the AG, the storage corruption for one of the node will leave you safe with the other node/nodes.
3. Readable secondary will help you in reporting purpose.
   [Active Secondary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/active-secondaries-readable-secondary-replicas-always-on-availability-groups?view=sql-server-2017)

The only disadvantage/Limitation of AG I would say is the need of Enterprise edition.

Comment: well, and if you want readable secondary, you need to license *two* Enterprise servers.    But you can have basic Availability Groups with SQL 2016 Standard.